# Can't run tornado app using gunicorn

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado, wsgi, gunicorn

I can't run tornado application using gunicorn. There is an error while startup app. I want to run it using gunicorn because I need some good features like: graceful-timeout, response-timeout and etc...

tornado app:

```
$cat wsgi.py
```

source code:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.wsgi
from api.handler import MainHandler, ApiV2Handler, InvalidRequestHandler


def app(*args):
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        (r"(/v3/(\w+)/(\w+)/)", ApiV2Handler),
        (r"(/v3/(\w+)/(\w+))", InvalidRequestHandler)
    ])
    return tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(tornado.wsgi.WSGIAdapter(app))
```

bash:

```
$ gunicorn wsgi:app --bind 127.0.0.1:9080
```

traceback:

```
[2015-07-06 14:41:16 +0000] [21806] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-07-06 14:41:16 +0000] [21806] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:9080 (21806)
[2015-07-06 14:41:16 +0000] [21806] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-07-06 14:41:16 +0000] [21811] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21811
[2015-07-06 14:41:21 +0000] [21811] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
    for item in respiter:
TypeError: 'WSGIContainer' object is not iterable
^C[2015-07-06 14:41:23 +0000] [21806] [INFO] Handling signal: int
[2015-07-06 14:41:23 +0000] [21811] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 21811)
[2015-07-06 14:41:23 +0000] [21806] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

Any ideas?

**Update** for Ben Darnell:

I tried this:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.wsgi
from api.handler import MainHandler, ApiV2Handler, InvalidRequestHandler


def app(*args):
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        (r"(/v3/(\w+)/(\w+)/)", ApiV2Handler),
        (r"(/v3/(\w+)/(\w+))", InvalidRequestHandler)
    ])
    return tornado.wsgi.WSGIAdapter(app)
```

But result is the same:

```
TypeError: 'WSGIAdapter' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Looks like gunicorn is expecting `app` to be the `WSGIAdapter` object and not a function that returns a WSGI app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works for me:

```
gunicorn -k tornado wsgi:app
```

wsgi.py

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.wsgi
from api.handler import MainHandler, ApiV2Handler, InvalidRequestHandler

app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"(/v3/(\w+)/(\w+)/)", ApiV2Handler),
    (r"(/v3/(\w+)/(\w+))", InvalidRequestHandler)
])
```

good luck!

Comment: does this allow websockets?

Answer (score 0):

To run in WSGI mode, return the WSGIAdapter; do not use a WSGIContainer (WSGIContainer is for going the other direction, when you have a WSGI application to run on a tornado server). However, gunicorn has a native tornado mode so you will probably get better results in this mode than using WSGI.